# Patch antennas: explanation of examples

Tags: antenna, balun, antenna-array

I am studying patch antennas for mobile communication (technology.)

I have found some examples of them but without explanation.

Maybe can someone explain to me the difference of examples from this picture?

[image]

**my thoughts:**

c) Is a patch which is connected with a waveguide (or linear antenna.)

f)  With a folded slot

But I am not sure, that' s why I need your help.

Comment: All of these are [PIFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted-F_antenna), a type of patch antenna.

Answer (score 0):

All these are not microstrip patch antenna but all these antennas are mostly fed with 50 ohms coaxial line (or SMA connector).

1. Option-C : This is inverted Wire antenna.
2. Option-d : This is Inverted-F wire antenna
3. Option-e : This is microstrip version of inverted-F antenna also called PIFA (Planar inverted F-antenna)
4. Option-f : It's also microstrip PIFA antenna with a slot cut on this. Slot is used to generate another resonance frequency (multi-band antenna)